# If first letter of source is 'M' or 'm' to return M

Tags: sql, oracle

I`m trying to get a specific result. The conditions are simple but still...
is query ok?

- If first letter of source is 'M' or 'm', load 'M' in target
- If first letter of source is 'F' or 'f', load as 'F' in target
- Else set to NULL

```
case when substr(GENDER,1,1) = 'M' then 'M',
when substr(GENDER,1,1) = 'm' then 'M'
when substr(GENDER,1,1) = 'F' then 'F'
when substr(GENDER,1,1) = 'f' then 'F'
else NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray comma and no `end` to the case expression, but apart from that what you have works.

You could simplify it to a simple (rather than searched) [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html):

```
case substr(GENDER,1,1)
  when 'M' then 'M'
  when 'm' then 'M'
  when 'F' then 'F'
  when 'f' then 'F'
  else NULL
end as target
```

or even shorter:

```
case upper(substr(GENDER,1,1))
  when 'M' then 'M'
  when 'F' then 'F'
  else NULL
end as target
```

or as the `else NULL` is implied you could leave that out too:

```
case upper(substr(GENDER,1,1))
  when 'M' then 'M'
  when 'F' then 'F'
end as target
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QeEZx0aH)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat simpler

```
case when upper(substr(gender, 1, 1)) in ('M', 'F') then upper(substr(gender, 1, 1))
     else null
end
```

but ... yes, your code would do as well. Didn't you test it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an uppercase letter with the whole word, do something like this:

```
SELECT upper(substr(GENDER,1,1))||substr(GENDER,2,length(GENDER)-1) as target
```

If you just need the short form like 'F' or 'M', you just need the first part of the statement mentioned before:

```
SELECT upper(substr(GENDER,1,1) as target
```

Comment: Your first query is using `+` so it will throw an invalid-number error; in Oracle the string concatenation operator is `||`. But the `initcap()` function would do the same thing, if the whole string was lowercase anyway. For both of them you will still get a non-null result for any gender value - e.g. `'other'` would return `'Other'` or `'O'`, rather than `null`.

Comment: You are right! Thank you. I edited the first statement. I also didn't notice the `ELSE` line in the description. I won't write a third statement, because we already got the right answer.